# Access to Excel: boolean is changed to numeric

Tags: excel, ms-access

I noticed that when transfering a query result from Access to Excel, whether by copy/paste or by using `DoCmd.OutputTo`, `True`/`False` values become -1 or 0 in Excel.
I could of course write a VBA proc to fill the Excel but I was wondering: is there any trick I could use to make the *simple transfer* work?  In other words, which value should I assign to the query column to get a proper `True`/`False` in Excel ?
I also noticed that in Excel, True is NOT equal to -1. It's not just a matter of formatting, like in Access.

Tried so far without success:

- using ´cBool´: nice `True`/`False` in Access, but turns also in  -1/0 in Excel
- changing the `Format` field property in the query to "True/False": same result

Comment: While `True` isn't the same as `-1`, Excel as well as VBA should recognize `-1` as `True` (as well as every other integer != 0). Can you provide an example? How do you want to have "`True`" represented in your Excel file?

Comment: @Verzweifler: They are not equal. Type 0 in B1, Type TRUE in B2, then in B3 enter the formula ´=B1=B2´ you will get FALSE.  
The file I create is used by a commercial program to import data in Accounting system, and it refuses when the column has 0 instead of FALSE.

Comment: I think `=` checks for identity, not "boolean meaning". I see that there's already an answer regarding the query side of the problem (probably what you want), but you should be able to use the Excel formula `=IF(0;FALSE;TRUE)` to get what you want as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you can use this expression to force a *True/False* string to Excel during export:

```
SpelledBoolean: Format([YourBooleanField], "True/False")
```

To return a 0 or 1, use Abs:

```
ZeroOneBoolean: Abs([YourBooleanField])
```

Comment: ´Format´ returns a string variant. I tried it but it does work. I also tried to change the Format property of the query field. That returns a nice ´True´or ´False´ in Access but again turns into 0 and -1 in Excel.

Comment: OK, then you can convert to 0/1 - see edit. Anyway, you may have in Excel to apply a format to that column of "True/False" for Excel to display this and not the numeric value.